# using multiple if else statements in one line

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is is possible to use multiple if else statements in one line?

I know just a pair of if else can be written as below:

```
weight = 50

if weight > 60:
    weight = 'heavy'
else:
    weight = 'light'

print(weight)
```

```
weight = 50
weight = 'heavy' if weight > 60 else 'light'
print(weight)
```

If I write two pair of if else, or use if else else else elif, how can I write that into one sentence?

```
weight = 50
height = 165

if weight > 60:
    if height > 170 = 'skinny'
        else : 'fat'
else:
    if height > 160 = 'skinny'
        else : 'fat'    
print(weight)
```

I know it is not recommended but just want to know.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want something like this, it makes it unreadable

Comment: You variable usage is very confused and some of your code is invalid.  Please fix the code and  make consistent use of weight vs score.

Comment: @DavidS I know it's unreadable and not recommended but just wanted to know if it is possible.

Comment: @AlainT. Sorry. I changed it to weight

Answer (score 2):

You can use mutiple-level if-else s

```
    weight = 50
    height = 165
    ans = ('skinny' if height>170 else 'fat') if weight>60 else ('skinny' if height>160 else 'skinny')
    print(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess using multiple ( ) is the way to do it but makers it very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it concise (at the expense of readability), you could write it like this:

```
score = "skinny" if height > [160,170][weight>60] else "fat"
```

or this:

```
score = ["fat","skinny"][height>[160,170][weight>60]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer